# How to automatically color lines in IDA?

Tags: ida

I want IDA to automatically color lines in both the graph and text view for important instructions, for example wherever there is a `call` or `xor` instruction change the background color of each of those references to a certain color.

Here is what I am looking to achieve:

[image]

*fig.1 graph view*

[image]

*fig.2 text view*

I noticed you can go to `Edit > Other > color instruction...` from the main menu and this will allow you to change the background color of the selected instruction, but this does not change all of them and seems to only affect the current database.

How can I make IDA automatically color certain instructions such as `call` and `xor`as shown from the example images?

I want it to automatically work for any database I open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write an IDA plug in using `IDAPython` (`python` for `IDA`) or `IDC` (`IDA` scripting language which is very similar to `C`), the following code is in `IDC`:

```
#include <idc.idc>
static main(void)
{
    auto currentEA;
    auto currentMnem;
    auto prevMnem;
    auto currentOp;
    prevMnem = "";
    currentOp;

    currentEA = FirstSeg();
    currentEA = NextHead(currentEA, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    while (currentEA != BADADDR)
    {
        currentMnem = GetMnem(currentEA);

       //Highlight call functions
       if (currentMnem == "call")
       {
           SetColor(currentEA, CIC_ITEM, 0xc7c7ff);
       }
    }
}
```

You can also refer to the opcodes' operands:

```
//Non-zeroing XORs are often signs of data encoding
if (currentMnem == "xor")
{
    if (GetOpnd(currentEA, 0) != GetOpnd(currentEA, 1))
    {
        SetColor(currentEA, CIC_ITEM, 0xFFFF00);
    }
}
```

Here is [a guide from ***Hex Blog***](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=120) for using `IDC` plug-ins.

And here is [a sample for similar script in `IDA Python`](http://practicalmalwareanalysis.com/setcolorssiko-py/) instead of `IDC`.

Comment: I found this page from one of the links you posted [http://practicalmalwareanalysis.com/2012/03/25/decorating-your-disassembly/](http://practicalmalwareanalysis.com/2012/03/25/decorating-your-disassembly/) and saved the ColorIDA.IDC script in my idc folder. If I am doing this right I then loaded IDA and went to `File > Script file..` and it was quite slow but eventually loaded and colored the `Call` lines. I couldn't figure out how to get it to run automatically though, I couldn't get the python ones to work either. First time working with scripts and I am a little confused what to do? Thanks

Comment: So I tried following this guide to get it to run automatically with not much luck: [http://fuzzynop.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/making-ida-pretty-pretty-quickly.html](http://fuzzynop.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/making-ida-pretty-pretty-quickly.html) Not sure what exactly I need to do?

Comment: I couldn't work out how to get it to run automatically when opening IDA but all I need to do anyway is load the script once and when I save the current database the next time I open it, it will instantly load with the script so that's good enough for me thanks.